# Jquery - Disable textbox, but still capture click event on the area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Like the question says, I am trying to capture a click on a textbox that is disabled.

Now, there may be a better way to do this, but right now I don't know it.  Basically I have a textbox that is disabled sitting in a div.  It is merely a placeholder.  I have an event that captures the click on anywhere within it's parent div.  Because the textbox is disabled, this does not work.

Does anyone know of a way to either:

1. Keep textbox enabled but don't allow the user to enter any input or display a cursor.  (Essentially make it just a static textbox that the user can't interact with at all)

or

1. Disable textbox like I am now, but continue to capture the click events.

This is what the input looks like:

```
<li id="test_id" class="selected">
  <label id="" for=""> Untitled</label>
  <input id="text" type="textbox" name="default" disabled="disabled">
  <div class="field_actions">
  <span class="propertiesTip"></span>
</li>
```

and this is what the click event handler looks like:

```
$('#parent').on('click' , 'li, label, textbox', function (event) { /*...*/ }
```

This handles a click anywhere inside the div.  It doesn't work on the textbox if it is disabled.  Anyone encounter this before and have a solution?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this was mentioned, but I would use read only. You can use CSS to style it to look disabled, and even to change the cursor to whatever you want like so:

```
input.myDisabledInput {

color: grey;
background-color: lightgray;
cursor:default

}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think I'm correct in stating:

Disabled values DO NOT get sent when a form is submitted.

Read-only values DO get sent when a form is submitted.

so, different behaviours... you need to be aware of them.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of disabled, make it readonly.

Comment: Problem is, that still makes it look like the user can enter an input value.  The curser shows up.  Is there anyway to disable this behavior?

Comment: Then trigger the `blur` event on the checkbox, when it gains focus. `$(your_input).focus(function() { $(this).blur(); });`

Comment: Can you override the cursor with CSS? Give the textarea a different class while it is in readonly, in CSS, define this class as one that will have a different cursor. When the textarea is enabled, remove this class to make it appear like a regular input item.